# How to disable the Guest account in macOS Mojave using `dscl`?

Tags: mojave, user-account, guest-account

I've attempted to disable the Guest account using `dscl` as follows:

```
sudo dscl . -append /Users/Guest AuthenticationAuthority ";DisabledUser;"
```

However, it doesn't seem to work, why?

I know, I can disable the Guest account from the GUI, but I like to use the CLI.

Comment: Do you have Find my Mac enabled? That makes the guest account compulsory, as a honey trap.

Comment: Don't think so. How can I check it? I could disable (remove from logon screen)  the Guest account through System Preferences, but not through the `dscl` command above?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to disable Guest user via command line

`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow GuestEnabled -bool FALSE`

Note, re-enabling it is quick, but you need extra help if you need to set this up without the first GUI step or MDM.

- [Enable Guest User in 10.14.x Via the Command Line (without a MDM)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346088/enable-guest-user-in-10-14-x-via-the-command-line-without-a-mdm)

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "set this up without the first GUI step"? Also, do you know why Guest can't be disabled using `dscl`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sysadminctl tool to query and modify sevurity status of users in Mojave.

Following command should query the guest account status:

```
sysadminctl -guestAccount status
```

And with administator permissions you should be able to disable it:

```
sudo sysadminctl -guestAccount off
```